# Cant find desired archetype when creating new Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, maven-archetype

I am trying to create a new Maven project in the terminal, using the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.my.domain -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeArtifactId=wildfly-javaee7-webapp-archetype -DinteractiveMode=false
```

So I am trying to use the Wildfly archetype `wildfly-javaee7-webapp-archetype`.

I am getting the following error...

```
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/wildfly-javaee7-webapp-archetype/1.0/wildfly-javaee7-webapp-archetype-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.860 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-31T14:35:27+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/188M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:wildfly-javaee7-webapp-archetype:1.0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

... which means, that Maven is trying to download the archetype at `https://repo.maven.apache.org` which is not correct, because the archetype is provided by `http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly.archetype`.

How can I change the source or how can I add additional sources? Or am I missing something different?

Comment: What repositories does your pom contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the [`archetypeGroupId`](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html#archetypeGroupId), otherwise, it will default to groupId of Maven default archetypes. Also, you need to define the [`archetypeVersion`](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html#archetypeVersion).

In this case, you need to have `archetypeGroupId=org.wildfly.archetype` and `archetypeVersion=8.2.0.Final` ([for example](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly.archetype/wildfly-javaee7-webapp-archetype/8.2.0.Final)).

Thus, you should have:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.my.domain -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeGroupId=org.wildfly.archetype -DarchetypeArtifactId=wildfly-javaee7-webapp-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=8.2.0.Final -DinteractiveMode=false
```

As a side-note, `repo.maven.apache.org` and `mvnrepository.com` both are Maven Central and contain the same artifacts.

Comment: Solved my problem! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else is having problems following the accepted answer try to decrement the version to `-DarchetypeVersion=8.1.0.Final`